# How to make special gray overlay in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

If you should do something like this overlay in Objective C how would you approach it?
http://screencast.com/t/Hgif0AtCFl

It must follow the current time of the day so I don't think an image will work - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using background image tiles:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lines_texture.png"]];
```